# jQuery add class on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container type of thing in my webpage. It contains a heading and a list. I want the heading to be underlined when the user hovers over the container. I tried it using CSS, but the underline only appears when I hover over the heading and not the container.

I'm very new to jQuery, still I tried to use it, but it's not working.

**Here's the part of my webpage:**

```
<div class="stuff">

<div class="subContainer">

            <div class="subHeading">

                Fruits

            </div>

            <div class="list">

                <ul>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Mango</li>
                <li>Orange</li>
                <li>Banana</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

</div>

</div>
```

**Here's the corresponding CSS:**

```
.stuff .subContainer{
    border: 2px #E65010 solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0 2.5em;
    width: 23.5%;
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.stuff .subContainer:hover{
    border: 2px #E65010 solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(230,80,16,0.2);
}

.stuff .subHeading{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.8em 0 1.8em 0;
}

.stuff .subHeadingHover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #E65010;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

.stuff .list{
    font-family: oswald;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
```

**And this is the jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".stuff .subContainer").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children(".subHeading").addClass(".subHeadingHover");
    });

    $(".stuff .subContainer").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children(".subHeading").removeClass(".subHeadingHover");
    });

});
```

Can you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: remove the `.` from `addClass(".subHeadingHover");`

Comment: you can do this in css, btw.

Comment: To clarify, @MichaelCoker means the `.` in the string you pass to `removeClass`.

Comment: you may want to use mouseenter and mouseleave, otherwise these events will also trigger when the children are hovered.

Comment: @DigitalRevenge awesome, you bet :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Can you please tell me how to do this is CSS?

Comment: @KevinB Okay. I'll change that. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah I got it at once. Still thanks.

Comment: @DigitalRevenge sure thing, submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in CSS, just add your `.subHeadingHover` css to `.stuff .subContainer:hover .subHeading`

```css
.stuff .subContainer{
    border: 2px #E65010 solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0 2.5em;
    width: 23.5%;
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.stuff .subContainer:hover{
    border: 2px #E65010 solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(230,80,16,0.2);
}

.stuff .subHeading{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.8em 0 1.8em 0;
}

.stuff .subContainer:hover .subHeading {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #E65010;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

.stuff .list{
    font-family: oswald;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="stuff">

<div class="subContainer">

            <div class="subHeading">

                Fruits

            </div>

            <div class="list">

                <ul>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Mango</li>
                <li>Orange</li>
                <li>Banana</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Got to learn many new things today. Thanks. You rock :)

Comment: @DigitalRevenge sweet! you're welcome :) *"Got to learn many new things today."* that's what it's all about!

Answer (score 1):

Update your JavaScript:

You need to remove `.` from `addClass("subHeadingHover")` and `removeClass("subHeadingHover")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stuff .subContainer").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children(".subHeading").addClass("subHeadingHover");
    });
    $(".stuff .subContainer").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children(".subHeading").removeClass("subHeadingHover");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this CSS by adding `.subContainer:hover`:

```
.stuff .subContainer:hover .subHeading{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #E65010;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

See your updated example below.

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1akhdxnf/)

Answer (score -1):

You can underline it using CSS

```
.stuff .subContainer:hover{
    border: 2px #E65010 solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(230,80,16,0.2);
}

.stuff .subContainer:hover .subHeading{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #E65010;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

Basically, you need to add a `:hover` on the container and not the heading.

Comment: What you suggested is not working out. No problem. I've got it sorted out. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I deleted the <script> to my js file while trying this.

Comment: Strange. Maybe you need to hover on the `.subContainer` instead then

Comment: My bad. Your code actually works. I just did a small mistake while copying the code.

Comment: Well. Do please remove the downvote in that case, if it was added by you :)

Comment: I'd love to but I didn't add it. I don't know who did it, but someone (probably the same person) downvoted my question too.